Expo Intent Launcher opens an empty image from the DCIM folder
Hello there
I use expo-intent-launcher to open the image that is downloaded and stored in the DCIM folder. My compileSdkVersion is set to 34. This is my code:
startActivityAsync('android.intent.action.VIEW', {
                    data: 'content:///storage/emulated/0/dcim/savedimage.jpg',
                    flags: 1,
                    type: 'image/jpeg'
                });

I get

exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()

error when changing content:/// to file:///.
When the code runs, it opens a blank image for me. The following image: (In fact, it does not find the image)

